# Magento - added product source?

Tags: magento, shopping-cart

I want to be able to apply certain rules to the products added to the shopping cart depending on where they were added from (product page, category page, wishlist). Is there any attribute(s) or methods I can call to find out where it is being added from? Maybe on Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item or Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Option?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will probably be better using the [event model](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method) to catch when the item is added to the quote.
There is an event for `sales_quote_add_item`

You could then write an observer  which checks the referrer and applies the rules.
Here is some very basic code, that should give you a starting point

**config.xml**

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_add_item>
            <observers>
                <apply_price_rules>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Your_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>applySpecialPriceRules</method>
                </apply_price_rules>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_add_item>
    </events>
</global>
```

**Observer.php**

```
public function applySpecialPriceRules($observer) {
    $referer = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getRequest()->getServer('HTTP_REFERER');
    $quoteItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();

    if(strpos($referer,'wishlist') !== false) {
        // apply rule 1
    }
    elseif(strpos($referer,'category') !== false) {
        // apply rule 2
    }
    else {
        // apply rule 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note you may want to check the current route instead of the referer. You can do this by using `getFullActionName()` instead of `getServer()`

Comment: That's a fair amount of information for me to work on. I didn't know a Magento way to get the referrer neither. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. I'll look into it further when I get to the office tomorrow.

Comment: I've added the config xml, and the method for getting the item out of the observer. Good luck.